# DuplicateKeyException and SqlCeException SQL Ce WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I have problem with windows phone 8 local database. That's how my database code looks:

```
  [Table(Name = "Folders")]
    public class FolderTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging, IEqualityComparer<FolderTable>
    {
        private string _folderName;
        private string _description;
        private string _password;
        private string _tileColorName;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public string FolderName
        {
            get { return _folderName; }
            set
            {
                if (_folderName != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _folderName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                if (_description != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _description = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                if (_password != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _password = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column]
        public string TileColorName
        {
            get { return _tileColorName; }
            set
            {
                if (_tileColorName != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _tileColorName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if ( PropertyChanging != null)
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if ( PropertyChanged != null )
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;


        public bool Equals(FolderTable x, FolderTable y)
        {
            return x.FolderName == y.FolderName;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(FolderTable obj)
        {
            return obj.FolderName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Folder add:

```
    public Task Add(Folder folder)
    {
        var folderTable = GetFolderTable(folder);

        _databaseContext.Folders.InsertOnSubmit(folderTable);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

Commit:

```
public Task Commit()
{
    try
    {
        _databaseContext.Folders.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException duplicateKeyException)
    {
        _databaseContext.Dispose();
        _databaseContext = new FolderDbContext(FolderDbContext.DBConnectionString);

        throw new FolderAlreadyExistsException(duplicateKeyException);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

When I `Add` new Folder (folder with such name didn't exist before), `Commit` and then I try add folder with same name `DuplicateKeyException` is thrown and handled correctly. However after context gets recreated in catch section the next call to Add and Commit folder with same name throws `SqlCeException` with message: `"A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = Folders,Constraint name = PK_Folders ]"`. Is that normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong? In what cases `DuplicateKeyException` is thrown? How to catch `SqlCeException`? I can't even see `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use reflection to get the type name of the ex eption, if you wish to catch the SqlCeException explicitly:

```
ex.GetType().Name == "SqlCeException"
```